# Find correct bucket for the number

Tags: sql, algorithm, math

I have a bucket that has different `3-3-4`, I need to find the right bucket for the number

`1-3 4-6 7-10 11-13 14-16 17-20 21 - 23  24 - 26  27 - 30`

What could be the efficient formula to find the right bucket, like number 5 lies in buckets `4-6`, 18 lies in the bucket `17-20`.

Need to write sql query for that

Comment: How big are the numbers (eg 1..30 in your example)?  If not too big, pre-populate a lookup table.

Answer (score 2):

I would maintain a separate bona fide table containing the range values.  Then, join to it to get the output you want.

```sql
Table: ranges
start | end
1     | 3
4     | 6
7     | 10
11    | 13
14    | 16
17    | 20
21    | 23
24    | 26
27    | 30

WITH buckets AS (
    SELECT 5 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 18
)

SELECT b.val, CAST(r.start AS VARCHAR(10)) + '-' + CAST(r.end AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM buckets b
INNER JOIN ranges r
    ON b.val BETWEEN r.start AND r.end
ORDER BY b.val;
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-overlapping ranges, you only need the starting value of each range (or, equivalently, the ending).  Then INDEX that column.  Then this is very efficient:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE n >= ?
    ORDER BY n
    LIMIT 1
```

Because of the INDEX, this runs in O(1).  (Or O(logN) if include the cost of the BTree lookup.)

More details (couched in IP-addresses):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges